# Trouble including third-party code in my C++ application

Tags: c++, include

I'm trying to include some networking code into my C++ application. I downloaded [CSimpleSocket](http://sockets.carrierlabs.com/) and I copied all the .h and .cpp files into the directory where my main file is. Then I tried including one of the headers, but the linker just barfs up a bunch of errors, like:

- [Linker error] undefined reference to CPassiveSocket::CPassiveSocket(CSimpleSocket::CSocketType)'
- [Linker error] undefined reference to `CSimpleSocket::Initialize()'
- [Linker error] undefined reference to `CPassiveSocket::Listen(unsigned char const*, short, int)'
- [Linker error] undefined reference to `CPassiveSocket::Accept()'

and others. Everything is in one directory, so I don't think that's the problem. The code I'm using to include is `#include "PassiveSocket.h"`. I'm using Dev-C++, if that makes any difference. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, so if somebody could help me, that would be great.

Forgive me if this is a really dumb question, but I'm trying to learn C++, and it's not easy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because your compiler can't find the binary that corresponds to the CSimpleSocket headers. It's as if you wrote

```
void someFunction(int someArg);
```

And then never provided the implementation for someFunction.

To use a third party library you need two things:

- Header files (.h, .hpp, etc...)
- Library files (.a, .lib, etc...)

Once you've got your header files and library files you need to put them in a place your compiler can find them. This place will vary depending on your OS, environment variables and compiler configuration.

Now that they're somewhere the compiler can find them you need to tell the compiler to use them. Header files are used with the #include command and library files are linked by providing arguments to the compiler.

Behind the scenes Dev-C++ uses the MinGW GNU GCC compiler, it invokes a command similar to `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ... filen.cpp -o filename` that tells the program g++ to compile a C++ executable named "filename" using files 1 to n. There are other flags that can be added to g++ such as telling it where to search and what to link.

The name of the CSimpleSocket library when compiled is "clsocket" so we need to find a way to configure Dev-C++ to add `-lclsocket` to the `g++` command. I don't use Dev-C++ so I can't help you here but you're probably looking for "Linking Options" or something similar in your compile configuration. You also need to make sure the .lib and .h files are on the search path which should also be configurable in Dev-C++.

CSimpleSocket also provides an installer that should automatically create the .lib file and place the .lib and .h in places where they can be found, you should consider using that installer.

I think the complexity of this answer highlights the abysmal state of the C++ library integration ecosystem. Unfortunately there is no concept of a "module" in C++ at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it explains a lot to me.

Ok, so I installed CSimpleSocket, added -lclsocket to the linker, and added the the path to those files to compiler search path. I'm pretty sure I did it all correctly. If I take out all the code, and just leave the include statement, everything compiles fine. But when I create an object, the linker gives all the same errors as before.

Comment: Sometimes the IDE will automatically add the -l so you might actually be linking -l-lclsocket, try just adding clsocket in the configuration.

Comment: I don't think that's it. When I get rid of the -l I get this error: `[Build Error]  [Server.exe] Error 1`

Comment: Try doing the g++ command manually, you might need to add the Dev-C++ bin directory to your PATH environment variable. This should give you more insight into the error. Also look at if there are additional libraries produces by CSimpleSocket (unlikely).

Comment: Admittedly, I don't know much about g++, I've never used it. But I tried compiling the files with it, and it gave a _huge_ amount of errors, most of the looking something like `C:/carrierlabs/clsocket/StatTimer.h:93: error: 'uint32' does not name a type`. It appears that g++ doesn't like this library at all.

Comment: If you're using the MinGW compiler you might want to try the linux sources instead of the windows sources.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Are you saying I should compile on linux instead of windows?

Comment: Sorry no. I had MinGW and Cygwin confused (MinGW compiles directly to windows while Cygwin expects linux-style sources). However you could try #include <cstdint> which defines uint32 (make sure to include it before the clsocket headers)

Comment: Well, now it can't find cstdint. I think I'll shelve this whole project and work on something else, now that school has started for me. I want to thank you for helping me try and figure this out. I appreciate it greatly. I'll accept your answer because you explained how everything works, which I didn't understand before. Thank you!